# WooCommerce product details page category display

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

WooCommerce product details page category display category tree like  parent display first and child display second

Comment: Can you explain with screenshot so I can clearly understand and will help you about this.

Comment: product details page screen short http://prntscr.com/n6qdy8  I need to display Categories:  Wheels & Tires, Wheels